# Folder don't see in DDMS whereas folder was created Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, directory, ddms

I don't understand why i can't see the folder that i had created in the DDMS of Eclipse.
At the beginning of my activity, i call this method :

```
 public void createFolderSignature(){

    File signaturePointFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "tour_"+this.point.getId_tour() + File.separator + "point_"+this.point.getId());            
    Log.i("PATH : " , signaturePointFolder.getPath());
    if (!signaturePointFolder.exists()){
           Log.i("signaturePointFolder","CREATED");
           signaturePointFolder.mkdir();
       }else{
           Log.i("signaturePointFolder","ALREADY CREATED");
       }
}
```

The **tour** and **point** are object. 
So i create a special folder in terms of id of point and tour.
Like you see, i pet log to see if the folder are create well.
So this is my logcat :

```
06-12 09:31:51.268: I/PATH :(24819): /mnt/sdcard/tour_1/point_1
06-12 09:31:51.268: I/signaturePointFolder(24819): CREATED
06-12 09:31:51.412: D/dalvikvm(24819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1101K, 10% free  12980K/14343K, paused 18ms+12ms, total 67ms
06-12 09:31:51.716: D/dalvikvm(24819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1706K, 13% free 13337K/15175K, paused 11ms+15ms, total 66ms
```

So if see my log "CREATED", i gather that normally, the folder is create well, but no, i see nothing in the File Explorer in Eclipse of my AVD.
And each time that i arrive to the activity, i have the same log.
Why? There are something wrong in my code?
I hope that you will can help me =)

EDIT 1 : 
i forget to say that i pet the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  and  READ_ too in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get  `Log.i("signaturePointFolder","CREATED");` because the file path always not exists.
So,Try this

```
public void createFolderSignature(){

    File signaturePointFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "tour_"+this.point.getId_tour() + File.separator + "point_"+this.point.getId());            
    Log.i("PATH : " , signaturePointFolder.getPath());
    if (!signaturePointFolder.exists()){
           Log.i("signaturePointFolder","CREATED");
           signaturePointFolder.mkdirs();
       }else{
           Log.i("signaturePointFolder","ALREADY CREATED");
       }
}
```

And don't forgot to add permission in `manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted,so it may help others also.

Answer (score 1):

Change `signaturePointFolder.mkdir()` to `signaturePointFolder.mkdirs()`
It's required since your creating a herarchy of folders. `mkdir()` works only when there is a single parent. Hence you need mkdirs() to create the remaining folders as well.

Also make sure that you are providing the write permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi Kindly tick the right mark and select this as the answer.